# Excel connection to password protected file

Tags: excel, protected, connection

Hi I have a excel file which connects to another excel file. There is only one connection but I want to connect to the password protected file. How do I connect to a password protected excel file from my excel file.

PS. I am using Excel 2010 on windows 7

Comment: Is the password worksheet protection, workbook protection, network share protection or something else?

Comment: The file was saved with a password option set when using save as with file explorer the excel file itself is read only thats the only thing